# USATST 2013/2 Prove that the intersection of $XL$ and $KY$ lies on $BC$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle. Circle $\omega_1$, with diameter $AC$, intersects side $BC$ at $F$ (other than $C$). Circle $\omega_2$, with diameter $BC$, intersects side $AC$ at $E$ (other than $C$). Ray $AF$ intersects $\omega_2$ at $K$ and $M$ with $AK < AM$. Ray $BE$ intersects $\omega_1$ at $L$ and $N$ with $BL < BN$. Prove that lines $AB$, $ML$, $NK$ are concurrent

**My Progress**:

**Claim** : $K,M,L,N$ is cyclic

**Proof** :
Let $NM\cap KL=H$ . Note that $H$ will be the orthocenter of $ABC$ .

By POP, $NH\cdot HM= CH\cdot CF=KH\cdot HL$.

**Claim**: $C$ is the centre of $(KMLN)$

**Proof**: Since $CA$ is the diametre , we have CA as the perpendicular bisector of $LN$ .

Similarly $CB$ is the perpendicular bisector of $KM$ .

---

[image]

Now , I just want to show AB is the Polar of $H$ wrt $(KLMN)$ . Then by Brocard's theorem, I know that $NK\cap LM \in AB $.

Comment: To clarify the problem, based on my understanding the points shown in the picture as $L,N,K,M$ are the points $K,L,X,Y$ in the original problem. If possible please edit the problem to match the picture ( I didn't edit as I might be wrong).

Comment: Also the points $A,C$ are actually $C,A$ in the original problem (swapped)

Comment: @cr001 done thanks! I think it's okay , right now ?

Comment: The question looks good now. In your proof of $C$ is the center, I think you mistyped $KM$ and $NL$ to be $MN$ and $KL$ but I think that's easily understandable so it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the polar of $H$ passes through $A$ as well as $B$. By symmetry it suffices to show the polar of $H$ passes through $A$ or equivalently, the polar of $A$ passes through $H$.

You know the polar of $A$ is perpendicular to $AC$

Observe that $$AC.AE=AK.AM= AC^2-r^2$$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle $KLMN$.

Rewriting this as $$AC^2-r^2= AC.(AC-EC)$$ $$ \implies AC.EC=r^2$$

Thus the polar of $A$ wrt $KLMN$ is the line perpendicular to $AC$ and passes through $E$. In other words it is the line $BE$ and hence passes through $H$.

Note: There is probably some disparity between the labeling in the question and that in the diagram. My answer follows the labeling of the diagram.

Comment: Great Proof ! I always forget about La hire's theorem

Comment: Thanks. It felt nice doing a problem like this after years. :)

Comment: Great application of La Hire! By the way, one could also have used $AN^2=AE\cdot AC=AK\cdot AM\implies AN$ is tangent to $(KLMN)$ - where the first equation follows from well-known relations in right triangles. From there, it is straightforward to infer that $EN$ is the polar of $A$ wrt $(KLMN)$.